# Displaying a notification only when a beacon is detected for a certain period of time

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, monitoring, ibeacon

I am very new to the andriod app programming and would like to ask about beacons.

Currently, I am using AltBeacon android-beacon-library to write an app.  There is one feature that I like to implement:

Ideally, I would like a notification to be displayed when a user is near a particular beacon.  However, I would only like the notification to be displayed if the user is around that beacon for more than 30 seconds.  If the user simply walk past the beacon, then I don't want the notification to be displayed.

May I ask if there is any existing methods for this?  I understand there is a method called "startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion" but I dont really know if this is a suitable method.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this easily with the Android Beacon Library using ranging.  Follow the regular tutorials on setting up ranging.  Then in your ranging callback add code like this:

```
HashMap<String,Long> beaconDetections = new HashMap<String,Long>();

public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Region region, Collection<Beacon> beacons) {
  Long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
    Long firstDetectionTime = beaconDetections.get(beacon.toString());
    if (firstDetectionTime != null) {
      if (now-firstDetectionTime > 30000l) {
        // Put logic here for if beacon seen for 30 secs or more
      }
    }
    else {
      beaconDetections.put(beacon.toString(), now);   
    }
  }
}
```

The code above uses a HashMap to track when each beacon was first seen, then executes special logic on each callback if it has been seen for 30 secs or more.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Am rather new to this so wanna clarify something: when you say set up ranging, do you mean using the method   startRangingBeaconsInRegion()?  What you mean by ranging callback?    Also, I am struggling to understand the difference between ranging and monitoring?  What's the actual difference?

Comment: Ranging sends a callback each second with the list of beacons detected after you call startRangingBeaconsInRegion().  Look at the Ranging Sample Code here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Comment: Thanks David, I finally figured out how the code works.  I have implemented a show notification method in your commented area.   However, there is one thing I don't quite get it.  If I want the app to show notification when " (now-firstDetectionTime > 30000l)", then after 30s, there will be a notification after a notification after a notification.  If I change it to (now-firstDetectionTime = 30000l), no notification would come up.  Why is that?  How do I ensure the notification would show once only?

Comment: The easiest way to make the code execute only once is to add a new HashSet to store whether an event has already fired for a particular beacon:  `HashSet<String> beaconEventsFired = new HashSet<String>();` then before firing your event wrap the code in `if (beaconEventsFired.get(beacon.toString() == null) {   beaconEventsFired.put(beacon.toString());  /* execute your code here */ }`

Comment: Thanks!! I tried to add the codes that your provided, and it said cannot find symbol method get(boolean) and it's referring to beaconEventsFired.get(), what should i do?

Comment: Managed to resolve this now - simply use "if (!beaconEventsFired.contains(beacon.toString())) { beaconEventsFired.add(beacon.toString()); /* execute your code here */ }

Comment: Want to ask one more thing.  If I want a notification to be displayed not only when the beacon has been seen for 30 seconds, but also when the proximity within that 30 seconds of that beacon is near or immediate.  How could I do that?  Do I need to create another hashmap?

Comment: You could just add an if statement in the innermost logic verifying that the beacon.getDistance() is within a certain range.

Answer (score 2):

Use Background services to get beacon availability with timer. Start Timer when you get beacon presence and trigger notification after 30 second if beacon is available at location for 30 second else reset the timer.

Beacon background search : http://developer.estimote.com/android/tutorial/part-2-background-monitoring/

Above tutorial link looks promising

```
    //start when found beacon in background

   Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                 //send notification
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 30000);
```

//Reset if beacon status false or unavailable

```
   if (timer != null) {
   timer.cancel();
   }
```

Comment: thanks.  Could you explain a bit more about background services?  Could you show me some codes if you don't mind?  I am rather new to programming so would like some more explanation.  Thanks :)